# Unable to Dual Boot/Install Aspire V3-112P with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, uefi, 16.04, windows-10

I want to Install Ubuntu 16.04 with Win 10 in UEFI. But no success. Every time ubuntu is installed successfully but it doesn't boot. Only Win 10 boots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me few days to finally find the solution.

Step - 1: Disable ***Secure Boot***.
In Aspire V3-112P the option to disable **Secure Boot** is blocked. You need to set a password for booting form **Security** (BIOS) to be able to bring the option to disable **Secure Boot**.

Step - 2: Download and install **Ubuntu 64 bit** only.

After restarting, it will boot directly to Win 10 without giving any option for booting into Ubuntu.

Step - 3: Download [boot-repair-disk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) and use it to fix the booting. If successfull you will see the boot menu for **Ubuntu** and **Win 10**.

Enjoy Ubuntu 16.04...